# Module Injection via requirejs in Angularjs Dependency Resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have been facing a problem in module injecting.

My sample `Flow is Up-->downward flow`.

This is my folder structure as

```
Like --> Folder User Contains -- UserModule
         User\Controller contains
          ---UserController1
          ---UserController2
```

Another --->  `GlobalModule` 
it is dependent on `UserModule` and i am Bootstrapping `GlobalModule` and on view I am calling like `ng-controller="UserController1"`

I am injecting UserModule inside UserController1, its returning error UserController1 is not a function

I have set up Modules as:

1) UserModule....

```
define(['angular'],function(angular){ return angular.module('UserModule',function(){});}
```

2) Inside UserController1

```
define(['User\userModule'],function(app){ return app.controller('UserController1',function(){
 ...
});}
```

but my UserController1 is not hitting..